Algorithm to split basket optimally
I have my project and got stuck while writing BasketSplitter class.
My input data is in JSON format and looks as follows:
[
"Steak (300g)",
"Carrots (1kg)",
"Soda (24x330ml)",
"AA Battery (4 Pcs.)",
"Espresso Machine",
"Garden Chair"
]

and my configuration data looks like that:
{
 "Carrots (1kg)": ["Express Delivery", "Click&Collect"],
 "Cold Beer (330ml)": ["Express Delivery"],
 "Steak (300g)": ["Express Delivery", "Click&Collect"],
 "AA Battery (4 Pcs.)": ["Express Delivery", "Courier"],
 "Espresso Machine": ["Courier", "Click&Collect"],
 "Garden Chair": ["Courier"]
}

As a result, the algorithm returns a breakdown of products into delivery groups in the form of a map. Its key is the mode of delivery, and its value is the list of products. I would like:

The algorithm divides the products into the minimum possible number of delivery groups.
The largest group contained as many products as possible.

The expected output (I think) should look like that:
{
 "Express Delivery": ["Steak (300g)", "Carrot (1kg)", "Cold Beer(330ml)", "AA Battery (4 Pcs.)"],
 "Courier": ["Espresso Machine", "Garden Chair"]
}


public class BasketSplitter {

public BasketSplitter(String absolutePathToConfigFile) {
}
public Map<String, List<String>> split(List<String> items) {
}

}

I think there should be some kind of dynamic programming there, but I have no idea how to figure it out.
Here is my not working solution:
    private Map<String, List<String>> deliveryOptions;

    public BasketSplitter(String absolutePathToConfigFile) {
        this.deliveryOptions = loadDeliveryOptions(absolutePathToConfigFile);
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> split(List<String> items) {
        int n = items.size();
        int [][] dp = new int[n + 1][n + 1];

        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            dp[i][i] = 1;
        }

        dp[n - 1][n - 1] = 1;

        for(int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            List<String> delivieries = deliveryOptions.get(items.get(i));
            for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(delivieries);
                int numberOfDeliveries = 1;

                for(int k = j; k > i; k--) {
                    List<String> currentDeliveries = deliveryOptions.get(items.get(k));
                    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(common);
                    tmp.retainAll(currentDeliveries);

                    if(tmp.isEmpty()) {
                        numberOfDeliveries++;
                        common.addAll(currentDeliveries);
                    } else {
                        common = tmp;
                    }
                }
                dp[i][j] = numberOfDeliveries;
            }
        }

        int minDeliveries = dp[0][n - 1];
        return null;
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> loadDeliveryOptions(String filePath) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, List<String>> deliveryOptions = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            deliveryOptions = mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), new TypeReference<>() {
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return deliveryOptions;
    }


add sample code what you have tried so far
